# URL Rewriting on a ISAPI shared server (using PHP)

Tags: php, isapi-rewrite

I need to rewrite URLs. The problem is that I am developing in PHP on an ISAPI server. An additional problem is that I am not the owner/manager of the server.

Is there any way to rewrite URLs for PHP on a shared ISAPI server?

Answer (score 0):

Does the host have ISAPI_Rewrite tool installed? If yes, you can use per-site configuration file named .htaccess to rewrite URLs for your site.

Comment: I am not exactly sure. I have tried a .htaccess file (that worked on my apache server) and it didn't work at all. How would I check?

Comment: Ask your host whether he has ISAPI_Rewrite installed on the server. If he does, try the testing rule from here: http://www.helicontech.com/forum/forum_posts-TID-10648.htm